# About rosserial_stm32 on STM32 L4 series

Tags: ros, rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Excuse me, I am not fluent in English.So I use machine translation.

I tried to operate STM32 L4 series using this library (https://github.com/yoneken/rosserial_stm32).

I referred to here(https://www.slideshare.net/k_yone/rosserial-stm32).

However, I got such an error.

`$rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=57600`

`[INFO] [1553585723.997853]: ROS Serial Python Node`

`[INFO] [1553585724.007428]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud`

`[INFO] [1553585726.113745]: Requesting topics...`

`[ERROR] [1553585741.116108]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino`

How can I solve this error?

##environment##

- Ubuntu 16.04 + kinetic
- STM32L476
- [rosserial_stm32](https://github.com/yoneken/rosserial_stm32)
- SW4STM32 + CubeMX + ST-Link

##used commands##

`$ code STM32Hardware.h`

In `STM32Hardware.h`

`-#include "stm32f3xx_hal.h"`

`-#include "stm32f3xx_hal_uart.h"`

`-#include "stm32f3xx_hal_tim.h"`

`+#include "stm32l4xx_hal.h"`

`+#include "stm32l4xx_hal_uart.h"`

`+#include "stm32l4xx_hal_tim.h"`

then...

`$ cd ~/catkin_ws`

`$ catkin_make`

`$ cd ./src/rosserial_stm32/src/ros_lib/examples`

`$ cp -r chatter ~/workspace`

`$ cd ~/workspace/chatter`

`$ rosrun rosserial_stm32 make_libraries.py .`

Start CubeMX and load chatter.ioc.

Configure peripheral settings.

`Configuration    chatter STM32CubeMX     5.0.1 Date    03/27/2019 MCU    STM32L476RGTx`

`PERIPHERALS    MODES    FUNCTIONS    PINS RCC    Crystal/Ceramic Resonator    RCC_OSC32_IN    PC14-OSC32_IN (PC14) RCC    Crystal/Ceramic Resonator    RCC_OSC32_OUT    PC15-OSC32_OUT (PC15) SYS    Serial Wire    SYS_JTCK-SWCLK    PA14 (JTCK-SWCLK) SYS    Serial Wire    SYS_JTMS-SWDIO    PA13 (JTMS-SWDIO) SYS    SysTick    SYS_VS_Systick    VP_SYS_VS_Systick TIM2    Internal Clock    TIM2_VS_ClockSourceINT    VP_TIM2_VS_ClockSourceINT USART2    Asynchronous    USART2_RX    PA3 USART2    Asynchronous    USART2_TX    PA2`

`Pin Nb    PINs    FUNCTIONs    LABELs 2    PC13    GPIO_EXTI13    B1 [Blue PushButton] 3    PC14-OSC32_IN (PC14)    RCC_OSC32_IN     4    PC15-OSC32_OUT (PC15)    RCC_OSC32_OUT     5    PH0-OSC_IN (PH0)*    RCC_OSC_IN     6    PH1-OSC_OUT (PH1)*    RCC_OSC_OUT     16    PA2    USART2_TX    USART_TX 17    PA3    USART2_RX    USART_RX 21    PA5    GPIO_Output    LD2 [green Led] 46    PA13 (JTMS-SWDIO)    SYS_JTMS-SWDIO    TMS 49    PA14 (JTCK-SWCLK)    SYS_JTCK-SWCLK    TCK 55    PB3 (JTDO-TRACESWO)*    SYS_JTDO-SWO    SWO PERIPHERALS    MODES    FUNCTIONS    PINS RCC    Crystal/Ceramic Resonator    RCC_OSC32_IN    PC14-OSC32_IN (PC14) RCC    Crystal/Ceramic Resonator    RCC_OSC32_OUT    PC15-OSC32_OUT (PC15) SYS    Serial Wire    SYS_JTCK-SWCLK    PA14 (JTCK-SWCLK) SYS    Serial Wire    SYS_JTMS-SWDIO    PA13 (JTMS-SWDIO) SYS    SysTick    SYS_VS_Systick    VP_SYS_VS_Systick TIM2    Internal Clock    TIM2_VS_ClockSourceINT    VP_TIM2_VS_ClockSourceINT USART2    Asynchronous    USART2_RX    PA3 USART2    Asynchronous    USART2_TX    PA2`

`Pin Nb    PINs    FUNCTIONs    LABELs 2    PC13    GPIO_EXTI13    B1 [Blue PushButton] 3    PC14-OSC32_IN (PC14)    RCC_OSC32_IN     4    PC15-OSC32_OUT (PC15)    RCC_OSC32_OUT     5    PH0-OSC_IN (PH0)*    RCC_OSC_IN     6    PH1-OSC_OUT (PH1)*    RCC_OSC_OUT     16    PA2    USART2_TX    USART_TX 17    PA3    USART2_RX    USART_RX 21    PA5    GPIO_Output    LD2 [green Led] 46    PA13 (JTMS-SWDIO)    SYS_JTMS-SWDIO    TMS 49    PA14 (JTCK-SWCLK)    SYS_JTCK-SWCLK    TCK 55    PB3 (JTDO-TRACESWO)*    SYS_JTDO-SWO    SWO`

``` SOFTWARE PROJECT `` Project Settings : Project Name : chatter Project Folder : /home/hoge1/workspace/chatter Toolchain / IDE : SW4STM32 Firmware Package Name and Version : STM32Cube FW_L4 V1.13.0 ```
`Code Generation Settings : STM32Cube Firmware Library Package : Copy only the necessary library files Generate peripheral initialization as a pair of '.c/.h' files per peripheral : No Backup previously generated files when re-generating : No Delete previously generated files when not re-generated : Yes Set all free pins as analog (to optimize the power consumption) : No`

`Toolchains Settings : Compiler Optimizations :`

then,generate code for SW4STM32.

At SW4STM32 ,convert C to C++.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319729/about-rosserial_stm32-on-stm32-l4-series/) by [Nyarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40636/nyarn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-03-27**:
What's the duplicate question?

**Comment by [Nyarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40636/nyarn/) on 2019-03-27**:
I'm sorry.I closed the question because I made a mistake with almost the same content. However, the other is waiting for moderation and can not see it.

**Comment by [Nyarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40636/nyarn/) on 2019-03-28**:
I tried to edit this question and reopen it because the other question had disappeared but I could not get enough points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SYN and Version mismatch problem are due to following:

- Your connection might be loose so double check your connection.
- Inside ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h look for protocol_ver,
- "The second sync byte is a protocol version. It's value is 0xff for the first
  version of the rosserial protocol (used up to hydro), 0xfe for the second version
  (introduced in hydro), 0xfd for the next, and so on. Its purpose is to enable
  detection of mismatched protocol versions (e.g. hydro rosserial_python with groovy
  rosserial_arduino. It must be changed in both this file and in
  rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py"
- change the value of the protocol_ver according to your ubuntu ROS version, you are using ROS kinetic so your version will be "0xfb", also make similar changes to your ROS master side.

---

Originally posted by [Roman41](https://answers.ros.org/users/58000/roman41/) with karma: 26 on 2021-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0